# remove account from Account Manager

Tags: android, accountmanager

I try to delete an account using this code but it's not working:

```
{
    AccountManager accMgr = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());
    Account[] accounts = accMgr.getAccountsByType(AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
    for (Account ac : accounts) {
        accMgr.removeAccount(ac, null, null);
    }
}
```

Even I had this code in my Authenticator:

```
@Override
    public Bundle getAccountRemovalAllowed(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account) throws NetworkErrorException {
        Bundle result = new Bundle();
        result.putBoolean(AccountManager.KEY_BOOLEAN_RESULT, true);
        return result;
    }
```

Something is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer was this line

```
accMgr.getAccountsByType(AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
```

here, I get the account by type which is wrong, I must get all accounts and loop to remove it, so the answer is replacing this line with **getAccounts()**

```
{

                    AccountManager accMgr = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());
                    Account[] accounts = accMgr.getAccounts();
                    for (Account ac : accounts) {
                        accMgr.removeAccount(ac, null, null);
                    }
            }
```